# Can Vader see the world around him in color?

Tags: star-wars

If you look at Vader's armor from inside, the eye holes were red-tinted.

[image: Vader armor from inside]

Does that mean Vader always sees everything around him in red? Is there a specific reason why his armor was designed such way which can give him disadvantage?

Comment: Terrible! Wait. That's "how does he smell under that suit?"

Comment: My answer show that he can perceived colour as well as objects into the infrared and UV spectra.

Comment: Anger fuels the dark side. Seeing red should be advantageous

Comment: @Arcy You mean to say Red color belongs to the dark side?

Comment: It was obviously meant to be symbolic of his final initiation into the darkside, rather than an accurate representation of how a futuristic helmet would really be designed.